# function placing best practice

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have the following code

```
 browserClick = () => {
    console.log("test");
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {

    const browserClick = () => {
      console.log("test");
    };
```

I just want to know whats the difference between declare a function before the "render()" and declaring a function inside the Render. Is there any particular scenario when I need to declare a function Outside and Inside? I am new to React so wanted to know whats the best practice when declaring a function.

TIA

Comment: Don't redefine a named function every time unless you need to. You don't need to here.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that everything in the render method is going to be run again and again and again every time the component is rendered. In your case you are better off leaving the browserClick function outside of the render method.

One scenario to create a function inside the render method is when you need to create a closure on some value. For example, if you are mapping over an array and you need your function to have access to the index of every element in the array. In this case you would probably create an inline function for every element.

Answer (score 0):

Outside declare,such as your code, will make a static handle of the function, if you pass it as property to child components(extend from PureComponent), it would not lead the child component to render.
Inside declare, you will pass different function handle to child component every call of render.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your component re-renders, it's going to invoke your `render` method.

If you have a function declaration or variable declaration inside of your `render` method, it's going to be continually re-created on each render.

That being said, on modern Javascript engines, it is very likely that the performance impact will be minimal if not negligible.

Here's a test you can run to see for yourself: https://jsperf.com/inner-function-vs-global-function

---

To play it safe, I'd recommend including only what is absolutely necessary inside of your `render` function. If not for a performance gain, it'll at least keep your code cleaner and easier to author.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that it gets declared everytime the component render when you initiate it inside `render()` method, I think it has to do with the scope of the variable/function that you are declaring.

If you declare it outside the class declaration, it becomes a global variable/function without access to `this` properties of the class (including `this.props` and/or `this.state`), unless you pass something as parameter. The best approach maybe is to put it inside class, but outside render, then call it with `this.browserClick`. In the end, you should use whichever fits your need.